# Metor allowing access to the public images folder for a cdn - router

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I am trying to allow my images and css to be accessed by a CDN, I think the path us being hijacked by my router.

```
Router.route('/:permalink', function () {
  this.render('item', {
      // path: '/:permalink',
    data: function(){
        var permalinkVar = this.params.permalink;

        return Items.findOne({permalink: permalinkVar});
      },
    });
```

});

Is there a way to make some paths like /images /css and /js exempt from this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put anything that you want to be exposed publicly into the public folder.  From the meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> **public**
>
> All files inside a top-level directory called public are served as-is
>   to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include public/
>   in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For
>   example, reference public/bg.png as `<img src='/bg.png' />`. This is the
>   best place for favicon.ico, robots.txt, and similar files.

So if you have an image at /public/images/image1.png, it can be accessed at yourdomain/images/image1.png.